# Hornetq: how to configure queue to send messages for all subscribers

Tags: java, jms, hornetq

For example I have a queue

```
<queue name="test.queue">  
    <entry name="/queue/test"/>  
</queue>
```

I want to configure it to send messages to 2 subscribers. By default it sends only to first. There is an option in ActiveMQ, but I didn't find the same in hornetq.

I found two similar topics:

[JMS queue with multiple consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008664/jms-queue-with-multiple-consumers)
and [Are multiple client consumers possible in hornetq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338133/are-multiple-client-consumers-possible-in-hornetq?lq=1)

But in my case subscribers are 2 different applications written in different programming languages.

I use stomp protocol to connect to hornetq in both applications.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use topics, not queues?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've found out that topic provide publisher/subscriber.